# Inequality $\left|z+w\right|\geq\left||z|-|w|\right|$ when $|w|\leq A|z|$.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z,w\in\mathbb C$ and $|w|\leq A|z|$ for $A>0$. I want estimate from below $|z+w|$. I proceeded as follows. Since
$$\left|z+w\right|\geq\left||z|-|w|\right|$$
and $-|w|\geq -A|z|$, I write
$$\left|z+w\right|\geq\left||z|-|w|\right|\geq \left||z|-A|z|\right|=|1-A| |z|$$
But I have a doubt, I think that this estimate applies only if $|z|-|w|\geq 0$. Are my steps correct?

Comment: How do you justify the step: $\left||z|-|w|\right| \ge \left||z|-A|z|\right|$ ?

Comment: Please, state in the title what is the inequality you want to prove, because $|z+w|\ge||z|-|w||$ is true in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly say
$$
|z+w|\ge\bigl| |z|-|w| \bigr|\ge |z|-|w|\ge |z|-A|z|=(1-A)|z|
$$
but when $A>1$ this inequality won't give any information.

For instance, if $A=2$, $z=1$ and $w=-1$, you have $|w|\le A|z|$, but $|z+w|=0$ and $(1-A)|z|=-1$. So it's impossible to deduce $|z+w|\ge|1-A|\,|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong and the issue is coming from the inequality $\left||z|-|w|\right| \ge \left||z|-A|z|\right|$ which doesn't hold in general.

Consider: $w=1$, $z=2$ and $A=5$. $\left||z|-|w|\right|=1$ while $\left||z|-A|z|\right|=8$